# Excel: Get Data From Workbook not getting all rows

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am getting data from another workbook (about 80k rows) however not all the rows are coming through. It is capping out at 45k rows (including header). It seems like an awfully round number so I'm wonder if there is a setting that is causing this. A month or so ago I was able to get more than 45k rows, but now I'm not and I'm not sure what changed. In query options I raised the maximum allowed (MB) but this did not allow me for more rows.

Comment: Hmmm.... that limit isn't in the list of [Power Query limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-query-specifications-and-limits-5fb2807c-1b16-4257-aa5b-6793f051a9f4)

Answer (score 0):

If I change the workbook, that I am trying to get data from, to a CSV. I am able to get all the rows. I guess this can be considered a partial answer.